# can not apply operator to operands

Tags: c#

> Error 3   Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Button' and 'System.EventHandler'
>
> Error    4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

```
  // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(636, 466);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Load);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Sudoko_Solver);
        this.Controls.Add(this.radioButton3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.radioButton2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.radioButton1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.userControl11);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); //ERROR HERE
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

I double clicked the form .. in the form-load function .. got these errors .. any help?

Comment: += use for assigning handler to any event, not component

Comment: it is automatically generated when i double click the form @Peyman

Comment: Can you show us the code in which these errors occur?

Comment: Please add the code in question...

Comment: Did you create a button named `Load`? That wrecked the form's `Load` handler; if you are using Visual Studio it should have told you that.

Comment: @CodeX, if you double click on component, it's automatically adding handler to specific event, like click, load, etc.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you adding an event to the form's controls ?
In line 4:

```
    this.Controls.Add(this.Load);
```

This is the problem not the Form Load event.

**Edit**: As others have said, simply rename the button you added to an other name other than `Load`.

It's a good practice to help avoid this problem by adding a prefix to all form controls. For example, all buttons might have a prefix `btn` - so your `Load` button would become `btnLoad`

Comment: also these lines are generated automatically when i double click the form in the designer.cs

Comment: Weird, the line I wrote is never generated by VS it makes no sense, I never saw it before...

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem.  As  Dour High Arch mentioned above, it appears the OP has added a field called `Load` of type `Button` which is conflicting with the `Load` event of the `Form`.

Answer (score -2):

in your form if you have any List View check the headers having name Load. You should not use this key word in the Header.

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your contribution should be a comment as @DanielM pointed out. Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).